# Is there a free modern software to displayer caller ID via Windows TAPI?

Tags: windows, gratis, phone, tracking

In the past there used to be softwares that could monitor caller ID of modems, but they seem to be gone nowadays, certainly the ones that utilize Windows' **TAPI**. Is there a **modern** software free or at least freeware (or even a script) that can pop up the number that just called?

[image: Caller ID pop up]

Comment: This might be overkill, but if you installed asterik (free pbx), and then install a free soft phone on your PC.  I am not sure about the TAPI, but a soft phone will definitely provide some kind of notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and just created [my own TAPI script](https://github.com/lwcorp/lwtapi) using Python. It displays incoming calls either in a popup or in a command prompt console.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using VZ Enhanced 56K for many years.

It works perfect and allows me not only to block specific numbers, but also specific CIDs along with area codes and other combinations using expressions, such as those "V" numbers using the expression `^[vV]\d{14}$`. I have tested it with multiple 56K external modems and it works well as long as you have the correct driver.

It can be downloaded [here](https://erickutcher.github.io/#VZ_Enhanced_56K). You will get the usual warnings from Windows and Norton about installing it since it is not commonly used, but ignore them.

Comment: Nice! But according to the description there's no popup, only a UI log. Also, where does it say it uses TAPI? And 2019 is not ancient history but also not exactly modern.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think TAPI clients have gone anywhere (though TAPI in general might be mostly replaced by various VoIP functions). Is there anything "modern" (subscription-based SaaS or server + browser client)? Probably not.

Some clients I've used in the past for testing:

http://www.xtelsio.com/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmon/

http://www.phoner.de/index_en.htm

Comment: By modern I simply meant working on modern systems. For example, your second link was last updated in 2013 . The first link is not free, which leaves just the third link in which "TAPI development was stopped in Phoner." (last updated in 2021 and doesn't work for me - TAPI devices shows a blank list, even TTS doesn't work).

Comment: I cannot test with Windows 11 if this is what you are using, but both C'mon and Phoner seem to be working on my Windows 10 64-bit. I haven't tested xtelsio at the moment but AFAIR some older versions were free. Are you sure you have TAPI service provider installed and configured to use modem? At the moment I'm not even sure if any universal modem TSP still is maintained, unimodem.tsp lists only 32-bit Windows XP (and 64-bit OS would require 64-bit TSP), so you might need modem manufacturer support.

Comment: Looking into Windows 10 control panel I see Unimodem 5 service provider installed by default, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Windows 10 64-bit too, can you show a screenshot of where to find that Unimodem? I have [this installed](https://ibb.co/vLMRZJQ) for driver support, and this specific modem used to show Caller ID through the obsolete [PhoneTray Free](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22phonetray+free%22) (according to search results it looks like 1.39 was the last version, but [it can't be installed nowadays](https://ibb.co/WBrMxZ2)). If you know a free TAPI terminal, I can try to catch caller ID right from there using Caller ID commands.

Comment: TSPs are listed in Control Panel / Phone and Modem / Advanced. Either C'mon or Phoner should list phone lines, but for a low-level API monitoring Julmar's phone.exe was often used. It looks like its original page has died, but it is still linked from https://www.xtelsio.com/hlp/en/snom/phone/test.htm. I don't think that any text-mode "TAPI terminal" exist, it would be rather inconvenient to use (but phone.exe is close to it). Are you sure PhoneTray was TAPI-based and not listening directly to AT commands?

Comment: About being sure - it's hard to prove since they deleted everything about PhoneTray Free and its thriving forum. But they did keep [a news announcement](https://blog.traysoft.com/2009/12/the-future-of-phonetray/) of _"We are working on the new, designed from scratch PhoneTray software that will be much better than PhoneTray Free \[including\] **Direct modem access.** PhoneTray Pro will work with modems directly without using Windows TAPI driver. This will improve caller id decoding and solve many problems with incompatible modem drivers."_

Comment: Well, turns out my modem is at the **absolute bottom** of [Phoner.de's settings](https://ibb.co/rtymkFr)! This indeed made it **work**. Meanwhile the phone.exe tool also [shows it at the absolute bottom](https://ibb.co/cCw5pRG) and also works if I choose it. But phone.exe is more of a one time test tool, while Phoner.de is not a good program - for example those blanks above, the fact that it keeps ringing even when the caller hangs, tries to block using alt+f4 to exit and takes up a lot of memory ([10 times more than phone.exe](https://ibb.co/ByLmPZ1) when they pretty much do the same thing).